# How to define a placeholder for an input of a stream field using stream API in pyrocms?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pyrocms

I am using community edition of Pyrocms, so cant really use the benefit of stream module that comes in pro edition. I am trying to work with Stream API.

I have defined a stream field's meta data as below:

```
$field = [
    'name'      => 'First Name',
    'slug'      => 'first_name',
    'namespace' => 'users',
    'type'      => 'text',
    'extra'     => array(
                     'max_length' => 50,
                     'placeholder'=> 'Enter your first name' //NOT WORKING
                ),
    'assign'    => 'profiles',
    'required'  => true
]
$this->streams->fields->add_fields($fields);
```

In the above code, I have declared a key `placeholder` inside `extra` and have written its value. But when I later use this stream-field in the form by echoing out as

```
 <?php echo $field['input']; ?>
```

Input field is rendered as expected and the validation is also working but the text for placeholder does not appear. Same is the case when I try to add extra class attributes when defining meta data for field. I have had a good look in pyrocms documentation. It says there is a way to define attributes for rendered input but have not shown how to do it. I tried adding it into `extra` also tried defining outside the `extra` but still I am not able to show up the extra attributes for the input fields. Also, when the type is set to choice, where should I put the default value for drop down menu or checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field type 'text' doesn't have a parameter 'placeholder', only 'max_length' and 'default_value'.

So you could copy the text field type, rename the folder and the class, place it in addons/default/field_types and add this parameter to the field type - basically writing your own field type. It's really easy and I made a gist for you: https://gist.github.com/marcogrueter/02b5e70f02402d999059

Comment: That is a very nice answer and I am sure this is the right thing to do.  However I am having some problems when input field is rendered. The positive thing is that when I inspected the rendered input elements I can see the class and placeholder attributes. But the value of these attributes are empty. `placeholder =""` . And there is a error message on the page telling `Message: undefined index: placeholder` on on (line 37, as per the gist you wrote for me). I am aware that I have given meta data as `'type' => 'paramtext'` and `'extra' => ['placeholder' => 'bla bla bla']`  @mgrueter